# Java: Resolve namespace conflict

Tags: java

We have a jar that we lost the source code to.  I decompiled the jar and created new source from it.  I want to then verify that the source code and the old jar have the same behavior. I am writing unit tests to do the verification the problem is that they both have same namespace / class name so I do not know how to disambiguate the old jar and the new source code.  What can I do or is it impossible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to only have one version on the class path at once to guarantee that you are running that version of the code.  Develop your unit test separate from the code so you can drop in either version.

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't have to do this, but it seems like the only apporach.

Answer (score 1):

Give the new source a temporary namespace for testing purposes. Then instead of import, you can refer your new classes as:

```
com.yourfirm.test.packagename.TheClassName
```

the old ones can be simply imported and refered to as `TheClassName`. This way you can tell by looking at your test cases which is which.

Or simply run the tests with `-cp oldpackage.jar` and then `-cp newpackage.jar`.

Comment: Tests need to automated off build code so this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but you have to mess around with class loading.  Instead of putting either of the jars on the classpath, you'll need to load them at runtime.  Check out [JCL](http://jcloader.sourceforge.net/) for a library to allow you to do this. (Disclaimer: I have never used JCL.)

Basically, each test would have to load the class from the old JAR, grab the results of the method you're testing, then unload that JAR, load up the new one, run the same method against the new version, and compare the results.

Answer (score 0):

I'd change which classes are being tested at runtime with the classpath.  This approach would be less error-prone in terms of ensuring that you're running the same test code against both binaries.  Otherwise you introduce more complexity around whether the tests are correct.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to execute the tests against both jars at the same time. I don't know of a way to disambiguate the old/new jars if they are both in the classpath.

If your unit tests output results to stdout/stderr, you could run the tests against the original jar and save the results. Then run the tests against the new jar and save the results in a separate file. Then diff the files.

Another approach would be to refactor the new source code so that it has a unique namespace. You could then test against both jars at the same time, but it could be a lot of work to make existing programs use the new jar.

Answer (score 0):

If you run your tests via ant (Junit-task), you can control the ant classpath seperately for both runs (once via jar, once via fileset of classes).